# Close Hidden Modal Dialog (Selenium) C#

Tags: c#, selenium

After using and closing a specific dialog box in Selenium Firefox, one of my buttons doesn't work. I get this error when trying to grab page source:

> Additional information: Unexpected modal dialog (text: Are you sure?) The alert disappeared before it could be closed.

I've tried the common solutions of:

```
IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
alert.Accept();
```

and

```
alert.Dismiss();
```

Doing some testing, after I can confirm that the dialogue box isn't being found at all, the IAlert does not run.

This dialog is preventing other actions- I can't grab the page source after any interaction with the dialog box.

I'm trying to close this hidden/invisible dialog box so my code can run. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, firstly is it alert?.some times model popups may not be alert. try to inspect element on that popup may be by using firebug. if you able to find httml elements then no need to use that alert command..

Comment: @muraliseleniumtrainer There is nothing visual to inspect. Whatever it is, it lingers from that other page as long as the browser is open, but it's not a popup or element that I can see or interact with. The goal is to clean it up so the tool can work.

Comment: As a note, opening a second dialog box and programmatically closing it resolves this error, but this isn't a great workaround for my program.